# Retrieve values from a path with several unknown childs with Firebase and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my database:

```
  "asks" : {
    "US" : {
      "Los Angeles" : {
        "task1" : {
          "ID1" : {
            "address" : "example1",
            "date" : "28-02-2017",
            "price" : "222",
            "user" : "userID1",
          }
        }
        "task2" : {
          "ID2" : {
            "address" : "example2",
            "date" : "28-02-2017",
            "price" : "252",
            "user" : "userID2",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to retrieve all numbers and append them into an array `asksList`. But the childs `task` and `ID` has unknown name. I'm using a class to append data in an array.

Here is my code:

```
refHande = ref.child("asks").child("FR").child("Île-de-France").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {

        print(dict)

        let ask = asksArround()

        ask.setValuesForKeys(dict)
        self.asksList.append(ask)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
   }})
```

Here is my askAround class:

```
class asksArround: NSObject {

    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var tel: String?
    var address: String?

}
```

This code "bypass" the `task` child whose the name is unknown. May be I should do this with the `dict` I retrieved, but how?